# Spring boot unpack application before executing

Tags: spring-boot, maven, cucumber

I got this error when running `cucumber` test via spring-boot jar

```
io.cucumber.core.exception.CompositeCucumberException: There were 2 exceptions:
  io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException(The resource jar:file:/Users/XTZ/IdeaProjects/eq-data/target/eq-data-0.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/xyz-service-starter-2.3.10-1.jar!/com/xyz is located in a nested jar.

This typically happens when trying to run Cucumber inside a Spring Boot Executable Jar.
Cucumber currently doesn't support classpath scanning in nested jars.
Feel free to send a pull request to make this possible!

You can avoid this error by unpacking your application before executing.)
```

My question is how to unpack before executing(`unpacking your application before executing`)?

Answer (score 0):

[The Spring Boot executable format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html) describes how Spring packages its executable jar files. For example:

```
example.jar
 |
 +-META-INF
 |  +-MANIFEST.MF
 +-org
 |  +-springframework
 |     +-boot
 |        +-loader
 |           +-<spring boot loader classes>
 +-BOOT-INF
    +-classes
    |  +-com
    |    +-example
    |       +-project
    |          +-StepDefinitions.class
    +-lib
       +-com.example:utilities:8.0.1.jar
       +-com.example:models:4.2.0.jar
```

By default Cucumber scans the entire classpath for step definitions. This includes `BOOT-INF/classes`, `com.example:utilities:8.0.1.jar` and `com.example:models:4.2.0.jar`. Cucumber can not scan inside the latter two.

If your step definitions and features are located in `BOOT-INF/classes` you do not have to unpack anything. Rather you have to instruct Cucumber to look for step definitions in a specific package.

If for example you are using the `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main` you can do this by setting the `cucumber.glue=com.example.project` property in `cucumber.properties` or passing `--glue com.example.project`. Otherwise see the documentation for your test runner on how to configure properties.

If your step definitions are located in either or both of the libraries you have to instruct the [`spring-boot-maven-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-repackage-parameters-details-requiresUnpack) to unpack these dependencies. Additionally you have to instruct cucumber to only scan the packages in that specific library i.e: `com.example.utilities` and/or `com.example.models`.

```
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <requiresUnpack>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                        <artifactId>utilities</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                        <artifactId>models</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </requiresUnpack>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

There is also a [Gradle equivalent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.5/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable-configuring-unpacking).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, my step definitions and features are located in BOOT-INF/classes so I tried to run -String [] argv = new String[]{"--glue", "com.xyz",  "com/xyz/test.feature"}; but still getting the same response.

Comment: That's because `xyz-service-starter-2.3.10-1.jar` also has a package starting with `com.xyz`. So either you have split packages between between your project and `xyz-service-starter-2.3.10-1.jar` or `com.xyz` is not specific enough. Try `com.xyz.project`.

Comment: I am not sure how to approach this, my BOOT-INF  has BOOT-INF/classes/com/xyz/eq/APITestContext.java so I am running String [] argv = new String[]{"--glue", "com.xyz.eq", "com.xyz.eq.test.feature"}; is it the right way to tell Cucumber where the package is?

Comment: Quite possibly. It depends on whether or not any of the jars in `lib` also have a `com.xyz.eq` package or not.

Comment: So if I get "You can avoid this error by unpacking your application before executing" what is the right way to unpack?

Comment: That's what `requiresUnpack` should do.

Comment: Yes but how do I set it to the right params? `<dependency>
                        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>eq</artifactId>
                    </dependency>`?

Comment: I've linked the docs and given an example. Not sure how to make this any clearer. Do make sure the dependency being unpacked is the one being scanned. If your application is `eq` it doesn't need to be unpacked. It's not in a nested jar.

Comment: I finally got it, but still it does not work for nested jars(set of jars from one dependency).